# Java8 function type for `(a,b) -> a+b`

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Trying to test Java8 lambda, but the type is confusing:

```
import java.util.function.ToIntBiFunction;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {

    int sum1 = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        sum1 += n;
       }


    ToIntBiFunction<Integer, Integer> add = (a, b) -> a + b;  
    int sum2 = IntStream.range(0, 10)
                        .reduce(0, add); //error here


     System.out.println(""+sum1);
     System.out.println(""+sum2);

   }
}
```

Test.java:15: error: incompatible types: ToIntBiFunction cannot be converted to IntBinaryOperator
                        .reduce(0, add);

What is the most generic way to define the function

`(a,b) -> a+b`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most generic way is as a lambda, once you assign it to a variable, or cast it to a type it become a specific type.

Try the type the reduce() expects

```
IntBinaryOperator add = (a,b) -> a+b
```

or use the built in one.

```
int sum2 = IntStream.range(0, 10)
                    .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

Comment: I like the built-in `Integer::sum` , thanks a lot Peter!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you need an `IntBinaryOperator` for the `.reduce()`, instead of `ToIntBiFunction`.

```
IntBinaryOperator add = (a, b) -> a + b;
int sum2 = IntStream.range(0, 10)
                    .reduce(0, add);
```